# Parallel loops running at different intervals

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

In C# I am trying to create a Windows Service with two loops that will run simultaneously at set intervals. For example, LoopA will run every 30 seconds and LoopB every 5 seconds.

The tasks that will take place inside LoopA could take more than 30 secodns to complete. If this happens, LoopA will begin again immediately, where as if the task only takes 20 seconds, LoopA will not run again for 10 seconds.

I have already implemented LoopA. My problem now is implementing LoopB to run in parallel, behaving in the same way as LoopA except with a 5 second interval. Here is my LoopA code, which runs inside a Thread:

```
private Thread Worker;
private AutoResetEvent StopRequest;

private TimeSpan loop_a_freq;
private TimeSpan loob_b_freq;

public LoopManager(Thread _worker, AutoResetEvent _stopRequest)
{
    // Threads
    this.Worker = _worker;
    this.StopRequest = _stopRequest;

    RunLoopA();
}

private void RunLoopA()
{
    DateTime start_current_loop = DateTime.Now;
    DateTime next_loop = start_current_loop + loop_a_freq;

    for (;;)
    {
        // Do processing here
        new LoopAction();

        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        if (now > next_loop)
        {
            next_loop = now;
        }

        TimeSpan delay = next_loop - now;
        Thread.Sleep(delay);

        next_loop += loop_a_freq;

        if (StopRequest.WaitOne(0))
        {
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

How do I go about implementing `RunLoopB()`? Threads are the one aspect of C# I have never explored fully. Do I need to use `Parallel.For()`?

Comment: Have you though about using a `Timer` to schedule your tasks. You can fire off threads at given intervals instead of having an infinite loop that sleeps.

Comment: I did, but there was an issue with the Timer not being able to properly handle tasks that exceed the interval time (so if the 30s task actually took 40s). My design spec has changed since then so it may be worth looking into.

Comment: A timer will fire of a new thread every given interval even if the previous thread hasn't finished. However there is nothing to stop you checking a variable at the beginning of the "work" task to see if there is already a task running then simply returning without doing anything if there is.

Comment: Would the Timer enable me to fire off two different Threads at different intervals and having them run in parallel?

Comment: Yes you just have 2 different timers with 2 different intervals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a little snippet you can put into linqpad and test with. This will prevent the timer from overlapping. Basically we execute the callback, stop the timer, process some work, reset the timer and start it up again. You would need a timer for each of your timed tasks.

To be clear, this will prevent your threads from needlessly queueing up as you are only creating a new thread to process work once the other one is finished. Having 2 timers will allow you to run 2 different processes at different intervals creating their own threads. Again, allowing only one instance of each process to happen per timer.

*Basic Process*

1. Setup Timer with no interval in constructor
2. Start Timer
3. Timer waits then when elapsed it kick off the process on a new thread
4. Process stops timer
5. Process does work
6. Process sets interval to reset timer (due to "AutoReset" property)
7. Process starts timer
8. Repeat from step 3

*Basic Code*

```
private System.Timers.Timer _timer;
private int _delaySeconds = 5;

void Main()
{
    // timer prevents threads from overlapping modify with care
    _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    _timer.Interval = _delaySeconds*1000;
    _timer.AutoReset = true;        // important to prevent overlap
    _timer.Elapsed += OnProcess;

    _timer.Start();
}

private void OnProcess(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs args)
{
    // timer prevents from thread overlapping modify with care
    _timer.Stop();

    // do work
    Debug.WriteLine("Processing on thread. [{0}]", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId).Dump("this");

    // setting the interval resets the timer
    _timer.Interval = _delaySeconds*1000;
    _timer.Start();
}
```

*Troubleshooting Performance*

Also, I found this article yesterday which may be helpful for you on diagnosing your threading performance.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee329530.aspx

Comment: Thnaks very much. Could you briefy elaborate on what you mean by 'threads overlapping'? If the two Timers are running side by side, how would the "overlap"?

Comment: Sure, you will be running both your timers in parallel spinning off their own threads so that part will work fine. This setup prevents ProcessA from executing again while it is still processing. It does this because ProcessA stops the timer, does the work, then starts the timer again. So basically ProcessA will only ever have one instance of it running at a time. So in other words, ProcessA and ProcessB can both be running but only one instance of either one with the above setup. If this is not clear I can rephrase.

Comment: You are a boss, Tony. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am new to threading as well and had just gone through all of this lol. Glad I could pass it on :)

Answer (score 2):

```
        using System.Timers;

        enum EventType {quit, task};

        class LoopDaLoop {

            Timer _30Seconds_publiser = new Timer(20000);
            Timer _5Seconds_publisher = new Timer(5000);

            Timer _terminator = new Timer(60000);

            BlockingCollection<EventType> loopAEvents = new BlockingCollection<EventType>();
            BlockingCollection<EventType> loopBEvents = new BlockingCollection<EventType>();

            public LoopDaLoop() {
                _30Seconds_publiser.Elapsed += _30Seconds_publiser_Elapsed;
                _5Seconds_publisher.Elapsed += _5Seconds_publisher_Elapsed;
                _terminator.Elapsed += _terminator_Elapsed;
                _30Seconds_publiser.Start();
                _5Seconds_publisher.Start();
                _terminator.Start();

                Task.Run(() => loopA());
                Task.Run(() => loopB());
            }

            void _terminator_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                loopAEvents.Add(EventType.quit);
                loopBEvents.Add(EventType.quit);
            }

            void _5Seconds_publisher_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                loopBEvents.Add(EventType.task);
            }

            void _30Seconds_publiser_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e) {
                loopAEvents.Add(EventType.task);
            }


            private void loopA() {
                while (loopAEvents.Take() != EventType.quit) {
                    // decrypt wife's personal email
                }
            }

            private void loopB() {
                while (loopBEvents.Take() != EventType.quit) {
                    // navigate attack drones
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be almost entirely ready to go, but in order to get the other thread running, you'll want to kick off the first thread in parallel, same for the second, and the wait them both. This might be easier using [`Task`s](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `Threads`, but here it is using `Thread`s

```
   public LoopManager(Thread _worker, AutoResetEvent _stopRequest)
    {
        // Threads
        this.Worker = _worker;
        this.StopRequest = _stopRequest;

        var threadA = new Thread(RunLoopA);
        var threadB = new Thread(RunLoopB);

        // Start the loops
        threadA.Start();
        threadB.Start();

        // Join the threads to avoid the program exiting before they're done
        threadA.Join();
        threadB.Join();
    }

    private void RunLoopB() {...} // As RunLoopA, but using the loop_b_freq variable
```

Now if you want to be able to ensure that each loop kicks off without waiting for the previous process to finish, you're starting to look at an implementation better served by the [`System.Timers.Timer` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx). Be aware there is also a `System.Threading.Timer` that you *do not want to use in this situation* because it lacks the event patterns.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. If I could click "accept" to more than one answer I would!